# Can you subscribe to a facebook page via rss?

Tags: facebook, rss

I have created a page and I would like users to be able to subscribe using rss (similarly as twitter). The only possibility I see is a subscription to notes, not the wall. Any ides how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no RSS feed for Profile Walls due to the complexity, permissions and the amount of posts to walls.

There is only RSS for notes:

Example:

> `http://www.facebook.com/feeds/notes.php?id={target_user_id}&viewer={viewer}key={key}&format=rss20`

Comment: This are notes from the Page, not the posts on the wall. I want to see the wall posts in the RSS feed.

Comment: @mauris FYI, 3 years later, this is possible :-)
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/15201579/910325

Answer (score 0):

This works for personal pages, but I don't think it works on other pages: To get everything on your wall (not just your own status posts), go to your notifications page and select RSS at the top where you have the options of getting either Text Message alerts or an RSS feed of what's on your wall.

Answer (score 0):

For every page on facebook the RSS url is:

`https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=xxxxxxx`

Where xxxxxxx is the page id. for example the ID for [ubuntu](https://www.facebook.com/ubuntulinux) page is 6723083591. so

`https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=6723083591`

is the RSS feed to that page.

mauris [answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/1677964/910325) while may have been valid in '09 it is possible to get the page feed :-)